# Unreachable code detected в switch

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
switch(System.Convert.ToInt32(BigInteger.Log10(value)) + 1)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        return value.ToString();
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        return value.ToString();
        break;
}
```

Break'и подсвечивает как `Unreachable code detected`, но такие значения точно возможны. Всё правильно или действительно у меня что-то не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break подсвечивается, потому что он тут лишний (он никогда не выполнится). Выход из switch происходит с помощью return:
 `return value.ToString();`